# Why does my workflow appear to be causing an infinite loop?

Tags: 2010, workflow, sharepoint-foundation, outlook

I'm JUST starting with workflows, and created my first one. We're running 2010 foundation, and I'm using the basic 3-stage workflow that's included.

I'm linking to a Word document in a library, and it's just a simple "do you approve of this document" workflow.

The email notifications about the task send properly, but when we click on the "open task" button from either Outlook or SharePoint, we get a dialog box that's showing about 1/3 loaded and says "Workflow Task details are being retrieved from the server. It's unresponsive to clicks (we need to force it to end in task manager) and it's flickering madly like it's going through screen refreshes. And CPU usage is up to abuot 70%. It looks and feels like some kind of infinite loop.

This dialog appears BOTH when we click e-mail links and when we navigate to the running workflows from within the library.

[image: Flickering dialog box].

Has anyone ever seen or heard of anything like this? Does anyone know the right places to look or the right questions to ask about how to fix the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I would check the email that the workflow is sending out to make sure that you have the correct site information being used as the URL for the task. If a generic url is being used it could be looping through the server confused as to where it should go.

Second, check the workflow process by going directly to the document library.
There should be an arrow dropdown menu on the title of your document that is waiting for approval. Click on "Workflow." Under Running Workflows you should see a line item that gives you the title of the workflow, the date and time it was initiated, and the status.

At that point you can click on the workflow title and it will take you to the workflow information page that gives you a handsome Visio visualization process and allows you to update the status.

Comment: The same thing happens from within outlook AND within the document library. Does that give you additional info?

Comment: Make sure that your SharePoint Server Enterprise Site features is activated. You can do this by going to Site Actions > Manage Site Features > SharePoint Server Enterprise Site features. If the activate button is displayed, activate it. This should resolve the issue.

Comment: We're using Foundation, there's no enterprise site feature to activate. Any other ideas?

Comment: Does the issue happen when you attempt to look at workflows on documents you have not started a workflow on? If so, I would double check permissions.

Comment: I also found a thread that suggested that this could resolve your issue if you find that the permissions are good. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepointcustomizationprevious/thread/6d5ffcb6-7563-4234-9282-e767b56b97b2

Comment: I am able to succesfully view workflows on documents without any workflows started on them. The link takes me to the list of active & available workflows...but no errors, no hangups.

Comment: From everything you have stated it looks as though somehow the task has been removed or deleted. It is also possible that the workflow itself did not create the tasks properly. I would try creating a second workflow on a different document and see if it works.